# How to get matched sub documents from mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("545dad3562fa028fb48832f0"),
    "key" : "123456",
    "members" : [
            {
                    "name" : "Shiva",
                    "country" : "India",
                    "profession" : "Software"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "Neil",
                    "country" : "Australia",
                    "profession" : "Software"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "anil",
                    "country" : "India",
                    "profession" : "Software"
            }

    ]
}
```

Now i want to retrieve the records with country India.
When i tried like this

```
db.user_details.find({ 'key' :'123456','members':{$elemMatch:{'country': "India"}}}, {'members.$': 1}).pretty()
```

When executed the above code i am getting only first occurrence, How to get all the matched sub documents(like `name:Shiva` and `name:Anil`) from that document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator along the the counterpart [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator will only currently match the **first** element that meets the conditions specified.

In order to get *"more than one"* match, the best method is to use the aggregation framework:

```
 db.user_details.aggregate([
     # Always match first to at least find the "documents" with matching elements
     { "$match": {
         "members.country": "India"
     }},

     # Use $unwind to "de-normalize" the array as individual documents
     { "$unwind": "$members" },

     # Then match again to "filter" the content down to matches
     { "$match": {
         "members.country": "India"
     }},

     # Group back to keep an array
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "key": { "$first": "$key" },
         "members": { "$push": "$members" }
     }}
 ])
```

That is the basic process for "filtering" more than one match from an array. The basic projection cannot currently do it.

Which returns this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("545dad3562fa028fb48832f0"),
    "key" : "123456",
    "members" : [
            {
                    "name" : "Shiva",
                    "country" : "India",
                    "profession" : "Software"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "anil",
                    "country" : "India",
                    "profession" : "Software"
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where should i put my `key` value in that query,Because with that above query no records are displaying.

Comment: @Mulagala Believe me if I run that against a collection with your data (corrected by be right now) then it returns just the elements with match `"country": "India" as asked.

Comment: Yes i understood, How can i get only particular document with a given condition check with key value 123456.Because i am getting the values with key `123` also not only key vlaue `123456`

Comment: Thanks i got it by placing `key` parameter in the `match` statements.Thank you very much